# Checking if a variable is not null

Tags: javascript

I am working on a CRM system that allows me to write custom HTML and JavaScript inside its interface, and I can reference CRM variables (such as current process status, date, etc) by using hash values `#variable.variablename#`. So I tried to write the following JavaScript but the problem is that no links will be displayed regardless of if any of the three variables exists or not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( #variable.1# != null) {
<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=5#variable.1#" >View Page</a></div> }

if ( #variable.2# != null) {
<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=5#variable.2#" >View Page</a></div>
}

if ( #variable.3# !=null) {
<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=5#variable.3#" >View Page</a></div>
}

</script>
```

What might be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guest that the content of `#variable.1#` (2 and 3) isn't valid javascript. Maybe you need to enclose them in quotes, like `"#variable.1#"`

Also, you need to `document.write` the html - you can't just put it on a line and expect to appear.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var html = '';
if ( "#variable.1#" != null) {
    html += '<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=5#variable.1#" >View Page</a></div>'
}

if ( "#variable.2#" != null) {
    html += '<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=5#variable.2#" >View Page</a></div>'
}

if ( "#variable.3#" !=null) {
    html += '<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=5#variable.3#" >View Page</a></div>'
}

document.write(html);
```

Also, consider using "View source" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on Firefox) to see the actual Javascript, you've constructed.

Comment: Pretty suspicious how yours is the only answer on the page that didn't get a simultaneous unexplained downvote

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in your code only the last link will be displayed incase the three varialbes have values.

Answer (score 1):

Those are invalid JS statements. To write content to the document, use `document.write`:

```
document.write('<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=5#variable.1#">View Page</a></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your CRM variables in single quotes, so they get interpreted as a string type in javascript, and use `document.write` to write html content, like this:

```
if ( '#variable.1#' != null) {
   document.write('<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=5#variable.1#" >View Page</a></div>');
}
if ( '#variable.2#' != null) {
   document.write('<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=5#variable.2#" >View Page</a></div>');
}

if ( '#variable.3#' !=null) {
   document.write('<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=5#variable.3#" >View Page</a></div>');
}
```